# Prove that a certain linear fractional transformation is a rotation.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\zeta \in \mathbb{C}$ be a primitive $n$th root of unity, and suppose that $f(z)$
is a linear fractional transformation that fixes the set $\{1,\zeta,\zeta^2,z_3,\ldots, z_{n-1}\}$.  Then $f$ permutes these points; if this permutation is given by the $n$-cycle
$$(1 \;\zeta\; \zeta^2\;z_3\;\ldots \;z_{n-1}),$$
is it the case that $z_k=\zeta^k$ for all $k$?  That is, do we have $f(z)=\zeta z$?

For $n=3$ this is easy: $f(z)$ permutes $\{1,\zeta,\zeta^2\}$ just as $\zeta z$ does, hence $\zeta^{-1}f(z)$ fixes three points.  This implies that $\zeta^{-1} f(z)=z$, as claimed.

I've also worked out the $n=4$ case in the affirmative, but my proofs do not hint at the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, not necessarily.

Any linear fractional transformation is conjugate to either $z\mapsto z+1$ or, for some $0\ne\alpha\in{\Bbb C}$, to $z\mapsto \alpha z$.  To have an orbit of size $2\le n<\infty$, $f$ must be conjugate to $g_\ell: z\mapsto \zeta^\ell z$ for some $\ell\in\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ which is relatively prime to $n$.  To get an $n$-cycle of the form $(1\  \zeta\  \zeta^2\  z_3 \ \dots \ z_{n-1})$, you can  conjugate $g_\ell$ by a linear fractional transformation $h$ such that $h(1)=1$, $h(\zeta^\ell)=\zeta$, and $h(\zeta^{2\ell})=\zeta^2$.  Setting $f:=hg_\ell h^{-1}$ will then give a map with an $n$-cycle $(1\  \zeta\  \zeta^2\  z_3 \ \dots \ z_{n-1})$, but $z_k$ need not equal $\zeta^k$.  For example, if $n=5$ and $\ell=2$, you would take
$$
f(z)=\frac{(2\zeta^3+2\zeta^2+\zeta+1)z+\zeta-\zeta^3}{(\zeta^3+\zeta^2+2\zeta+1)z-2\zeta^3-\zeta^2-\zeta}
$$
and then
$$
z_3=\frac{-3\zeta^3+7\zeta^2+3\zeta+9}{11},
\ \ \ z_4=\frac{3\zeta^3+12\zeta^2+6\zeta+10}{11}.
$$